# userID in accessToken

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Why is `userId` provided along with accessToken ? Can we not find `userId` using filter from AccessToken APIs? .Can any one explain the logic ?

As of now API (`GET /accessTokens/{id}`) is DENIED for all. How can we override the same so that `userId` can be traced.

```
{
    "id": "UksV2aTVyKfUAzBm8cQKRO9NkCIKUHZCXXr4gZNrCj9zXBiUX8kXVE97RDQl1PcC",
    "ttl": 1209600,
    "created": "2016-02-25T11:21:13.253Z",
    "userId": "56cbf0beda568ffb103b78bc"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I highly doubt you could obtain the user id from the access token (basically, reverse the token) **just by computation**, since it is a crytographically [generated](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#accesstoken-createaccesstokenid) token.

If your goal is limit access to a certain resource to a certain user, you need to establish a relation between the model and userModel, for instance `UserModel` `hasMany` `ForumPosts`

This way, you can know whether a specific `ForumPosts` instance belongs to a specific `UserModel` instance (= a specific user).

Then you set up Access Control:

- DENY all to everyone
- GRANT $owner a specific method of `ForumPosts`

You can then call rest endpoint like `DELETE api/UserModel/{userId}/ForumPosts/{modelId}?access_token=UksV2aTVyKfUAzBm8cQKRO9NkCIKUHZCXXr4gZNrCj9zXBiUX8kXVE97RDQl1PcC`

However, this is not sufficient. an authenticated user with ID = 1 could call the endpoint with id = 5, and the request would pass.

So you need to make sure the userId provided in the endpoint matches the JSON token. Best way is to use an [operation hook](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks), like `before delete` in this case and check there that generating a token from the endpoint-provided userId matches the token passed along.

Hope this helps

Comment: 'id' attribute shared in login response ("id": "UksV2aTVyKfUAzBm8cQKRO9NkCIKUHZCXXr4gZNrCj9zXBiUX8kXVE97RDQl1PcC") is actually the 'id' of accessToken Object. Relations are in inbuilt in loopback framework. I feel only Token need to be shared in login response and userID can be retrieved from accessToken Object ( provided API 'GET /accessTokens/{id}' is given an Access rights of $Owner)

Comment: The `id` returned after a POST to login is without doubt the access token itself. See here at the end if you're not convinced https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Introduction+to+User+model+authentication

Comment: However, you can get the userId from the AccessToken REST API however, because there is a relation `accessToken` `belongsTo` `User`defined here https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/access-token.json This way it's possible, except I'm not sure what id you should use, the access token itself or its id inside the database. Sorry if I cannot help you further, but my knowledge on loopback ends here